# After 11 comments, PHP keeps missing HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I made this website, http://mihaialin793.esy.es/new-homepage/portofolio/physics/, which has a comment form. The problem is, when I press submit, after the 11 comments the HTML gets messed up, the last comments gets hidden or deleted, and I can't figure it out.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']){

        print "<h1>Your comment has been sent!</h1>";

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $comment = $_POST['message'];

        #Get old comments
        $old = fopen("comment.txt", "r+t");
        $old_comments = fread($old, 1024);

        #Delete everything, write down new and old comments
        $write = fopen("comment.txt", "w+");
        $string = "<div class='comment'><span class='name'>".$name.":</span><span class='comm'>".$comment."</span></div><br>\n".$old_comments;
        fwrite($write, $string);
        fclose($write);
        fclose($old);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    #Read comments
    $read = fopen("comment.txt", "r+t");
    echo "<h2 class='other_comm'>Other comments</h2>".fread($read, 1024);
    fclose($read);
?>
```

The html is there on the website but I'll let them here too:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <h2>Post your comment</h2>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br />
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Comment"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'fread' method only outputs 1024 bytes in your case.

Instead try using:

```
echo "<h2 class='other_comm'>Other comments</h2>".fread($read, filesize('comment.txt'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I'm a noob at php.

Comment: Don't worry about it. it's free to learn :-). Good  luck with your project!